# Trouble understanding calculating basis of image of a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A: \mathbb{R^4} \rightarrow \mathbb{R^3}$ be a linear transformation which has in standard basis a matrix:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 3 & 1 & 4\\
1 & 2 & 1 & 3\\
2 & 2 & 2 & 4
\end{bmatrix}
$$

When calculating the basis of an image of this linear transformation, since the first two columns of the matrix are linearly independent and the dimension of the image is 2, we have just taken these two columns to form a basis of an image $\{(1,1,2), (3,2,2)\}$.

I don't really understand why can we do this?

Comment: If you have a vector (sub)space of dimension $k$, then any linearly independent set of $k$ vectors from this space will form a basis of the space.

Comment: So basically all 4 columns in the matrix represent the vectors in the image of the transformation?

Comment: Yes, that is correct

Answer (score 1):

Notice that the rank of $A$ is $2$ which eventually tells you that dimension of *image space* of $A$ is also $2$ i.e. **dim(image(A))**$=2$. Further, **Imagesp(A)**$\subseteq \mathbb R^3$ is equivalent to the *column space* of $A$ (generated by linearly independent vectors $(1,1,2)$ and $(3,2,2)$) so as their dimensions too which suggests that the basis of **Imagesp(A)** must be $\{(1,1,2),(3,2,2)\}$.

Answer (score 1):

Just the Nitin's answer with some details. If we note by $c_1,...,c_4$, the $4$ columns of the matrix $A$, you can see that $c_3=c_1$ and $c_4=c_2+c_1$. So any linear combination of the four vectors may be written in terms of $c_1$ and $c_2$:
$$\mathrm{Image} A=\mathrm{Span} (c_1,...c_4)=\mathrm{Span}(c_1,c_2)$$
Since $c_1$ and $c_2$ are linearly independent, they form a basis of the image de $A$.